# Send Android Beam with URI data

Tags: android, nfc, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-beam

I'm trying to implement Android Beam in an app that will not be distributed through Market.  There is a one-to-one correspondence between my app's activities and pages in a particular web page.  The behavior I would like is for it to attempt to open my app, and if it is not installed to go to the corresponding web page.  The app already has `IntentFilters` to handle the `ACTION_VIEW` for those URLs, and I'd like to leverage that.  I already tried using `NdefRecord.createUri(String uriString)`, but it always opens the stock Android browser (It won't even go to alternative browsers if installed).

In the `onCreate()` of my `Activity`:

```
NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { NdefRecord.createUri(getAppUri()) });
NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this).setNdefPushMessage(msg, this);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Beam Intents have the action set to ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED (not ACTION_VIEW), so you should filter for that instead.